# Why does Apple have a BIC code registered for them?

Tags: banking, swift

*From https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466770/why-does-apple-have-a-bic-code-registered-for-them?noredirect=1#comment691333_466770*

> It's not unusual for a legal entity to have an IBAN, but why does a company that isn't a bank have an entire SWIFT BIC code (APLEUS66XXX) registered for them?
>
> <strike>The sole other company which appears to have done the same is Google (GOOGUS66XXX) which leads me to believe that it must relate to the Apple and Google Pay services, respectively.</strike>
>
> Scratch that - Microsoft is registered as MSFTUS66XXX.

Comment: What does this have to do with Personal Finance? How are your personal finances influenced in any way at all by knowing why Apple has a BIC code?

Comment: @nobody, per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81647/623996, I was directed here because the name of this Q&A forum is, although initially *personal finance*, also merely *money*.

Comment: It's actually "personal + { finance | money }"

Comment: That's difficult to believe without a citation, and I've not seen any indexed by Google in a brief search for one. Are you able to provide me with one, and perhaps the name of whichever forum I should use instead?

Comment: See this [meta thread](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/should-we-remove-the-money-part-from-the-site-name-and-logo-to-prevent-repe)

Comment: @RokeJulianLockhart That Meta.SE post does not control what is on-topic here. Read https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for the actual rules.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Apologies for not being able to upvote them - it appears I've not the reputation yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These companies (and some others) have tens/hundreds of billions of dollars in their treasuries and operate inhouse investment banks to manage that.

They also have vast international presence through branches, subsidiaries, and investments.

As such they're directly connected to swift to facilitate their money management.

Comment: I am thankful for this, although I've marked https://money.stackexchange.com/a/159335/92333 as the answer per https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/why-does-apple-have-a-bic-code-registered-for-them?noredirect=1#comment328806_159335. In the interest of accuracy, do you believe your answer to be more accurate, however?

Comment: I do. Neither Apple Pay nor the Apple branded cards have anything to do with SWIFT, Apple Pay does not process transactions for banks, and no, Apple card is not issued in-house.